# Reasons for convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I am interested to know if anyone can see the reasoning behind the convergence $$\int_{\Omega}c(u_{k},\nabla u_{k})(u_{k}-u)dx \rightarrow 0$$ in equation (2.82), page 50 in the following book Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations with Applications by Roubicek.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what is the domain here?

Comment: @Jacob Hi, the domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a bounded, connected Lipschitz domain (it is stated in chapter 2.4 page 40 the book, please see link in the question).

Comment: You can't expect people here read this book to help you understand the equation. You will have to elaborate a little bit the details so they can see your problem from there.

Comment: what is $c$? probably, $u_k$ is bounded in $H^1$ thus weakly convergent (up to a subsequence). Rellich's embedding theorem provides another strongly convergent subsequence in $L^2$. Using the properties of $c$ will provide the convergence

Comment: You should start improbing your question or answering on comments instead of using bounties to get attention. By the way isn't the book copyrighted?

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the proof of the book $u_k\to u$ in some $L^p$ spaces and the $c$-term is bounded in an approporiate dual of $L^p$. With Hölder's inequality you can obtain something like
$$\int c(u_k,\nabla u_k) (u-u_k) \leq C \|u-u_k\|_p\to 0$$ for an approriate $p$.
The constant $C$ depends on the the norm of $c(u_k,\nabla u_k)$ in the appropriate space

Comment: where did you post that solution? is the domain bounded? Could you please update your question with all important assumptions?